# Trying to install NetBSD 7.1 on QEMU/KVM

Tags: linux-kvm, qemu, netbsd

I am using OpenSUSE Leap 42.2 on a Dell Inspiron 1545. 
An error occurs when I try to load NetBSD into QEMU/KVM: "module 'cd9660' pushed by bootloader already exists."
I installed Lubuntu 16.04 LTS in QEMU/KVM previously.

Comment: Are there any other messages after that?  Or are you seeing the first screen of the installation after this. (normally, this is a warning, saying that the kernel was asked to load the module twice.)